# Counting the number of digits in an integer string in Java

Tags: java

I have a char array (let's say of size 4). I am converting it into a string using:

```
String str = String.valueOf(cf); // where cf is the char array of size 4.
```

This String can contain `01` or `11` or `001` or `011`, etc. 
Now, I need to calculate the number of digits in this string. But every single time I calculate the number of digits(preferably in Java), it shows 4 as the result(Maybe due to the size 4). How do I calculate the no. of digits according to input string?

Example: If 001 is the input, it should give o/p as 3 and so on.

Here's the coding part :

```
static long solve(int k, long n)
    {

  //  System.out.println("Entered Solve function");
  char[] c = new char[4];

  long sum = 0;
  char[] cf = {};

  for(long i=2;i<=n;i++)
  {

      cf = fromDeci(c, k, i);
      String str = String.valueOf(cf);


       //System.out.println(snew);
       sum = sum + str.length() ;
    }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: ***But every single time I calculate ...*** how are you doing that..?? post that code please

Comment: Why is `str.length()` not good enough?

Comment: str.size() returns the number of all chars, but he only wants the digits - a char can be much more than digits.

Comment: @ManuelM. True. Depending on where the `char[]` gets its data, maybe it is known to only have numerical characters.

Comment: The above asked ques. is actually a part of a ques. So, I.m just attaching the required part..                                                                                                        static long solve(int k, long n)
    {

      //  System.out.println("Entered Solve function");
      char[] c = new char[4];

      long sum = 0;
      char[] cf = {};

      for(long i=2;i<=n;i++)
      {

          cf = fromDeci(c, k, i);
          String str = String.valueOf(cf);
          sum = sum + str.length() ;
        }

      return sum;
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question. You cannot format code in a comment.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `char[]` instead of `int[]`?

Comment: do you need the number of digits (=count) or the sum? also what does the method fromDeci do?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice,    Yeah, I'm actually converting a Decimal number to a binary number , etc and counting the number of digits returned by the fromDeci function.

Comment: @ManuelM. Yeah, I'm actually converting a Decimal number to a binary number , etc and counting the number of digits returned by the fromDeci function

Comment: @AshishRamtri The `char[]` array will always have 4 bits (not digits) in it. Why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: It will really help if you provide a [mcve] so that we can compile and run your code ourselves. Also explain in more detail how what you are currently getting is different than what you expect. Give an example input and describe what the output should be and why. Then show what the output actually is.

Comment: I just used the code posted by Manuel M and phatfingers and it's working now. Anyway, thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: Please consider accept an answer, it's how a forum works, by give points to those who spend time to answer you ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Stream API from java 8, solution in *ONE-LINE* :

```
String s = "101";
int nb = Math.toIntExact(s.chars()                     // convert to IntStream
                          .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)      // convert to char
                          .filter(ch -> isDigit(ch))   // keep the ones which are digits
                          .count());                   // count how any they are
```

Answer (score 1):

Is very easy with a regex:

```
String test = "a23sf1";
int count = 0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: @AshishRamtri If we helped you, an upvote / accept ot the answer(s) would be nice :-)

Comment: I tried upvoting the answer but it's showing this :  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "

Answer (score 1):

You can verify whether a character is a digit by simple comparison against digit characters.

```
private int countDigits(char[] cf) {
    int digitCt = 0; 
    for (char c : cf) {
        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) digitCt++;
    }
    return digitCt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! I don't know why this thing didn't pop up into my mind. It's now working correctly. You just saved a lot of my time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can use the Apache Commons :
(see [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getDigits-java.lang.String-))

For example :
`StringUtils.getDigits("abc56ju20").size()`

It gives you 4.